# php loop folder get the file names and size

Tags: php, filesize, glob

I want make a loop of my fold, get all the files and make a judge,  print all the files name witch size are less than 10kb. But I get nothing from this code (no php error hint, just 0 result, and I am sure there has 10 files at lest < 10kb), where is the problem? Thanks.

```
$folder = dirname('__FILE__')."/../images/*";
foreach(glob($folder) as files){
 $size = filesize(files);
 if($size<10240){
  echo files.'<br />';
 }
}
```

Comment: @Martin, Tim Cooper, user551841, thanks, but it still nothing return...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a typo, because

```
dirname('__FILE__')
```

should be (without quotes)

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

and also, your variable `files` doesn't have a dollar sign

```
$size = filesize($files);
```

and also here `echo $files`

That's it, it should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

1. `__FILE__` is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php), therefore you cannot wrap it in quotes:

   ```
   $folder = dirname(__FILE__)."/../images/*";
   ```
2. You missed a `$` in `files`:

   ```
   $size = filesize($files);
   // and
   echo $files.'<br />';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure

```
$folder = dirname('__FILE__')."/../images/*";
```

is valid? do you mean

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```