# How to make a php script that reads filenames and details from any directory and stores it on database?

Tags: php, file, server

I am given a lot of video files on my server folder, so adding all of them is impossible, I need to develop a php script that will read the contents of a folder and populate my database table with details such as filename, size, path, etc.
Furthermore I need to use that data for displaying the video list to users so everything must be accurate.
Please tell me how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use Iterators from SPL (Standart PHP Library) for an OOP aproach, for recursive iterations you should use `DirectoryRecursiveIterator`;

```
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/");
$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator);

foreach ($recursiveIterator as $filename => $fileInfo) {
    $filesize = $fileInfo->getSize();
    $path = $fileInfo->getPath();

    //insertDataIntoMysql($filename, $filesize, $filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639622/php-loop-folder-get-the-file-names-and-size) to see how to loop through a directory and get the filenames and file sizes. (Copied and edited here for simplicity)

```
$folder = '/my/path/to/dir';
foreach(glob($folder) as $file){
    $size = filesize($file);
    echo "Name=$file, size=$size<br />";
}
```

Instead of using `echo` to display the results you will simply use mysqli or PDO functions to run an `INSERT` query to insert into your table.  Since this is not input coming from a user it is not so imperative to use `prepare` and `bind` but it is good practice to do so (and more efficient as well).

Then when you display the video list you will once again use mysqli or PDO functions to run a `SELECT` query and then `echo` these values onto your page in appropriate HTML syntax.

I'm guessing, based on your question, that some of these concepts might be new to you. If you do not know how to program in PHP or use SQL or create HTML pages then you are going to need to spend some serious time going through tutorials and watching youtube videos and reading books.